# Sparse matrix in npz format in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a sparse matrix in numpy's `.npz` format. I know that to read this matrix I need to use [`scipy.sparse.load_npz()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.load_npz.html), but would like to understand its internals.

I see in the preview of the `.npz` file that it contains the following 5 parts:

1. data
2. format
3. indices
4. indptr
5. shape

How can I better understand this file format?

Comment: How familiar are you with the `scipy.sparse` package?  `save_npz` writes the basic attributes of a sparse matrix, enough to recreate it with `load_npz`.  What it writes depends on the sparse `format`.  In this case it's either a `csr` or `csc` matrix.  You could use `np.load` to look at these 5 values, but that's not needed to use `load_npz`.  If you understand the sparse format, the `npz` parts are pretty obvious.

Comment: It might help if you told us more about why you want to know this.  Just curiosity, or do you intend to use the parts directly?

Comment: @hpaulj i used scipy.sparse.load_npz and i put the result in the variable. I wish use this matrix for SVD ,but this matrix have a part data (that is a vector) and i don't know if my matrix (after the load) is the final matrix that i need to use (the tf_idf) or other format. I need TF-IDF for clustering. I used a bit scipy.

Comment: The result of `loadnpz` will be a `sparse` `matrix` as described on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html.  If `tf_idf` accepts scipy sparse matrices you shouldn't need any further processing, but I'm haven't used that application.

Comment: Because i Need sparse Matrix, but i dont understand why have too much attribute, and i m worry that Is a wrong way. The format Is csc i forgot to say you. I use often the dataset and after i Will trasform in sparse matrix

Answer (score 1):

npz is a simple zip archive, which contains numpy files. Simple review of internal structure of ZIP can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

Here are the docs:

Format of .npz files https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html

Format of .npy files
http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/pydoc/numpy.lib.format.html

Comment: I don't think the general `numpy.savez/load` helps this user.  Scipy.sparse `save_npz` uses `np.savez` to write attributes of a sparse matrix, but users usually don't need deal with the details.